# Listview item fits to row

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview with two textviews in a row like name and result.  I want to fit the textview to the row because I need to set a background color to the second textview.I have tried "match_parent"fill_parent"..etc
[image] 
    //items.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:layout_width="22dip"
    android:layout_height="22dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtViewDescription"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtViewDescription"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/temperrr"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/resultarrawnocolor" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

//    listview.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/gl1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="backMan" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textVie3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gl1"
    android:background="@drawable/header_line" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/gl2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textVie3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/info"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="info" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textVie1"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gl2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gl2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/uchek_header"
    android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/bgnf1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textVie3"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bag" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView1"
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bgnf1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textviewtableheader"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Result"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnemail"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/email"/>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsave"
   android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/save"
     />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnrec"
   android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myTextView1"
    android:background="@drawable/rec"
     />

 <ListView
android:id="@+id/lv1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/btnemail"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myTextView1"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myTextView1"
android:layout_below="@+id/myTextView1"
android:background="@color/White"
android:divider="@drawable/tabledivider"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/listcolor"
tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: from your item.xml add textviews in a linerlayout and add layout_weight for them 0.5 for both they will fill all space

Comment: do you want to display TextView with 50% width each?

Comment: can you edit the answer.?

Comment: @PareshMayani yup exactly and second textview's right end there is an image of an arrow

Comment: @Aaloka right or left? I can't see in "I want like this" image.

Comment: what about using linear layout(horizontal) with layout weight for the items layout.

Comment: @PareshMayani I edited the question can  you  see now.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the height to be of icon size you can use this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="#F00"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Envelope" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="#990"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="1000ml/Dl" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we increase the width of the row.?

Comment: No. width of the listview can be up to width of device. If you have sufficient size icon above code will give you same size text view. Else you can keep height as wrap content and add padding top and bottom to the text view to get expected height. This will also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="22dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/temperrr"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtViewDescription"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtViewDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewLogo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#ffff00"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/temperrr"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

may be this will help, i edited the answer,check now

Comment: How can we increase the width of row .?

Comment: try to set width fill_parent of listView

Answer (score 0):

Try distributing the weight of ImageView , TextView , TextView and ImageView to get the desired result.

Comment: Instead of using relative layout use LinearLayout. Then use the property  'android:layout_weight="2"'..